# Spring Data JPA: Using Example to filter date as string

Tags: spring, jpa, java-11, examplematcher

Trying to test if a LocalDate contains a given year, day or month.

For example, given the criteria "1979", I'd like filter the rows returned by a `findAll(Example<S> example)` JPA query in such way that it will return any row containing "1979".

The "problem" is that the entity defines the date (let say a birth date) as a `LocalDate` and as such, doing:

```
ExampleMatcher personFilter = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll()
.withMatcher("birthDate", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers
.contains().ignoreCase());

personPage = repository.findAll(personFilter);
```

with PersonFilter#birthDate being itself a `LocalDate`.

Basically, I would have to have this entity to declare the birth date as a String for the filter to work, but that is not possible as the DB itself store it as a `date`.

Is there a way to solve such problem ? Like overriding the way the matching work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you don't.

For more advanced use cases and predicate definitions, have a look at the [Querydsl support](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

---

The long answer is:

[Query by Example (QBE)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) is a user-friendly querying technique with a simple interface. It allows dynamic query creation and does not require you to write queries that contain field names.

#### Query by Example is well suited for several use cases:

- Querying your data store with a set of static or dynamic constraints.
- Frequent refactoring of the domain objects without worrying about breaking existing queries.
- Working independently from the underlying data store API.

#### Query by Example also has several limitations:

- No support for nested or grouped property constraints, such as firstname = ?0 or (firstname = ?1 and lastname = ?2).
- Only supports starts/contains/ends/regex matching for strings and exact matching for other property types.